# C++ Which thread calls the destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

If I create a `thread_local` object, its destructor is called on the thread it was created on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct MyStruct {
    ~MyStruct() {
        std::cout << "Destructed on thread #" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
};

void f() {
    thread_local MyStruct myStruct;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(f);
    std::cout << "Created thread #" << t.get_id() << std::endl;
    t.join();
}
```

```
Created thread #16920
Destructed on thread #16920
```

Does the C++ standard guarantee this behaviour? It only states this:

> A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before
> its first odr-use (6.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on
> thread exit.

Comment: "_shall be destroyed on thread exit._"

Comment: each thread has its own instance, why would some other thread destroy one threads object?